# How to build Primecoin from source code on a mac?

Tags: installation, compiling, primecoin

How should one build the client for the new cryptocoin [Primecoin](http://bitcoinmagazine.com/primecoin-the-cryptocurrency-whose-mining-is-actually-useful/) from source code on a mac?

The source can be found here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/primecoin/files/

Comment: Do you have any specific problem when building it? My guess (without really knowing) is that a good start would be to look at how to build Bitcoin on a mac.

Comment: looks like primecoin tells you to build it the same way to build bitcoin. they never even changed any info on the read me
https://github.com/primecoin/primecoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md

or assume you are using linux try those directions
https://github.com/primecoin/primecoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.md

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md should work for you as Joe White commented, note you'll have to install Xcode first of all, and in Xcode open preferences - downloads and install the command line tools. I recommend homebrew over macports as it's better maintained and a little more user friendly.

the only difference is that as you're downloading from sourceforge rather than github, you skip the git clone and just find makefile.osx in /src/src/ of the downloaded folder.

you then (assuming you installed homebrew as standard) open makefile.osx in textedit or xcode and change

```
DEPSDIR=/opt/local
```

to

```
DEPSDIR=/usr/local
```

and you'll probably have to change

```
 $(DEPSDIR)/lib/db48/libdb_cxx-4.8.a \
 $(DEPSDIR)/lib/libboost_system-mt.a \
 $(DEPSDIR)/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.a \
 $(DEPSDIR)/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.a \
 $(DEPSDIR)/lib/libboost_thread-mt.a \
 $(DEPSDIR)/lib/libboost_chrono-mt.a \
 $(DEPSDIR)/lib/libssl.a \
 $(DEPSDIR)/lib/libcrypto.a \
```

to paths more like

```
 $(DEPSDIR)/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1e/lib/libssl.a \
 $(DEPSDIR)/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1e/lib/libcrypto.a \
```

Check in /usr/local for the Cellar folder and the libs folder, you could alternately alias each referenced file in /usr/local/libs